# Java lambda expression-Count the number of appearances

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

So I have the following class and the ArrayList of objects:

```
class Ticket{
    String destination;
}

ArrayList<Ticket> tickets;
```

What I want is to get from my list a Map of String and Integer which contains the destinations from tickets and the number of occurences in my list for each destination. I think it would start like this, but I don't know how to continue:

```
Map<String,Integer> map=tickets.stream().filter(a->a.getDestination()).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of a [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector and the [summingInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) collector like this:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = 
  tickets.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Ticket::getDestination, 
                   Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)));
```

In this case, I've specifically used the [summingInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) collector due to the fact that the [counting()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--) collector returns a `Long` type and since you want the map values as  `Integer`'s then the [summingInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) collector is the most appropriate.

Comment: To get `Map<String,Integer>` type, this is the nice solution.

Comment: @Aominè you shoul explain why not `Collectors.couting`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `groupingBy` [collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html).

```
tickets.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Ticket::getDestination,
        Collectors.counting()));
```

This will give you a `Map<String, Long>`.

If you want a map with `Integer` values, you can replace `counting` with a `summingInt` that simply returns `1` (which is what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48355861/7366707) does)